# How to get DD/MM or MM/DD through Date Picker in IPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I need only DD/ MM in my picker for getting Birthday

I am capable to get MM/DD/YYYY through this code

```
datepickerView = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 40, 0, 0)];
    datepickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
    [datepickerView addTarget:self action:@selector(changedDate:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [actionSheet4 addSubview:datepickerView];
    [datepickerView release];
```

could you please help me out to get only MM/DD or DD/MM through Date Picker

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the following code:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"'dd'/'MM'"];
NSDate *anyDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:@"2019-09-11"];   
[datePicker setDate:anyDate];    
[dateFormat release];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get it as -

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd"];
NSString *str = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[datePickerView date]];
```

Answer (score 1):

You will always get a full NSDate object form the datepicker.
With the NSDateFormatter or NSDateComponets your can get specific values from the received  NSDate.